# WebStorm Dart set current working directory

Tags: dart, webstorm

Is it possible to set the current working directory for dartvm applications in WebStorm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not currently possible. Please vote for [WEB-11665](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-11665)